# AngularJS ng-class after :active or :focus

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a form I am trying to create using CSS to achieve a halfway "material" feel. I achieved a lot of the animations by ditching the stock bootstrap forms entirely and rewriting them to get the maximum amount of flexibility.

EDIT: Forgot to link Codepen - http://codepen.io/h3xc0ntr0l/pen/ONwdLm

Essentially, the "form groups" are set to `position:relative` and used to position the input and a couple pseudo elements absolutely, yada yada. I am using angular and am not able to incorporate jquery into the project.

my problem is as follows

```
<div class="-form-group">
   <input type="email" class="-form-input" ng-class='{"content":"user.email"}' ng-model="user.email"/>
   <span class="in-email"></span>
</div>
```

this does not have the behavior i need. I guess if I have "ng-model", then whatever is in there is going to evaluate to true.

I also tried the following with scss:

```
  .-form-input{
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2em;
    position: relative;
    z-index:4;
    &:active, &:focus{
      .in-email &{ //
        &:before{
          top: -50%;
          color: transparent;
          border-bottom: transparent;
        }
      }             
    }
  }
```

the effects are achieved via

```
.in-email, .in-pwd{
    &:before{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index:3;
        color: black;
        transition: 500ms ease all;
        border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgba(128,128,128, .5);
    }
 }
```

I can not think of anything else that would prevent the span from coming back down after i leave the hover regardless of whether or not there is any content. does anyone have any tips?

```js
(function(){
  angular.module('app').controller([
    '$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.user = undefined;
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: .25px solid #e9e9e9;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  height: 20rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
form .-form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: 500ms ease;
  margin: 0 1em 2em 0;
}
form .-form-group .-form-input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}
.in-email form .-form-group .-form-input:active:before, .in-email form .-form-group .-form-input:focus:before {
  top: -50%;
  color: transparent;
  border-bottom: transparent;
}
form .-form-group input:-webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #e9e9e9 !important;
}
form .-form-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  transition: 250ms 500ms ease all;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #288690;
  width: 0;
}
form .-form-group:hover:after, form .-form-group:focus:after, form .-form-group:active:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  top: 90%;
}
form .-form-group:hover .in-email:before, form .-form-group:hover .in-pwd:before, form .-form-group:focus .in-email:before, form .-form-group:focus .in-pwd:before, form .-form-group:active .in-email:before, form .-form-group:active .in-pwd:before {
  top: -50%;
  color: transparent;
  border-bottom: transparent;
}
form .button {
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: none;
}
form .in-email:before, form .in-pwd:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  color: black;
  transition: 500ms ease all;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}

.content:before {
  content: "" !important;
}

.in-email:before {
  content: "Email Address";
}

.in-pwd:before {
  content: "Password";
}

.nav, .pagination, .carousel, .panel-title a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#ui-root {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.ui-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
}

.button {
  background-color: #288690 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="ui-container">
    <div class="row" id="ui-root">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <form autocomplete="off" class="text-center">
          <!-- chrome autcomplete -->
          <div class="-form-group">
            <input type="email" class="-form-input" ng-class='{"content": "user.email"}' ng-model="user.email"/>
            <span class="in-email"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="-form-group">
            <input type="password" class="-form-input" ng-class='{"content": "user.password"}' ng-model="user.password" />
            <span ng-class='{"content": "user.password"}' class="in-pwd"></span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary button">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You wont find a lot of success on this forum by pasting huge chunks of code, you need to isolate your poblem more and be more specific with what  the desired effect you want to achieve is, and what is wrong.